# How to Implement Custom Fingerprint UI Using BiometricPrompt

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

We can provide custom UI in FingerprintManager Api but that is deprecated in API level 28. Now android has provided BiometricPrompt API and it's is providing default fingerprint dialog. I have gone through many articles, blogs and tutorial but haven't found any solution for adding custom UI instead of default dialog. Any suggestion or approach would be helpful.

Thanks!!